# How to set environment variables in Netbeans 8.0.2?

Tags: java, r, netbeans, jri

I'm running a test class that came with my JRI (Java-R interface) package. I'm running it through NetBeans. Unfortunately, NetBeans complains about R_HOME not being set.

```
Creating Rengine (with arguments)
Rengine created, waiting for R
R_HOME is not set. Please set all required environment variables before running this program.
Cannot load R
Unable to start R
```

How can I add the R_HOME environment variable in NetBeans?

---

What I have tried:

1. I defined R_HOME in .bash_profile and .bashrc.
   `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources`
2. Right-clicking my project name > Properties > Run ... but then I see nowhere to add environment variables. I only see "Arguments" and "VM Options".

---

I just a couple solutions (in the past half hour).

1. Add the line `export R_HOME=/path/to/r_home/` in netbeans.conf.
2. Invoke NetBeans from the terminal, where R_HOME is already set.

However, still open to a GUI solution.

Comment: Can you please type in your console " R.home()" and show us the results?

Answer (score 2):

In Netbeans 12 (but I think this works also on previous versions), right click on project and open the `Properties` window.
Go to `Actions`, then select `Run project`. Near the "Set Properties" label there is an `Add` button, click on it and select the option `New Environment Variable`.

This will generate a new line like this:

```
Env.FOO=bar
```

**Important**: notice that the variable is named `FOO` and the `Env.` prefix is used to indicate that it is an environment variable. If you remove the prefix the value will be passed as a system property (`-DFOO=bar`).

[image: Screenshot of Netbeans 12 actions needed for adding an environment variable]

Remember to set this also in the `Debug project` section if you need to use the debugger.