# Set up MPJ Express in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, mpi, linux-mint, mpj-express

I keep obtaining the same identical error as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32491813/running-mpj-express-on-eclipse).
I'm running eclipse under linux mint 17.3.

I've tried to add to MPJ_HOME to system variables writing this command on the terminal:  `export MPJ_HOME=/path/to/mpj/` (giving the real path to the folder of mpj) but the when I compile eclipse keep telling me:

```
[MPJRun.java]:[MPJRun.java]:MPJ_HOME environment found..
java.lang.Exception: [MPJRun.java]:MPJ_HOME environment found..
    at runtime.starter.MPJRun.<init>(MPJRun.java:155)
    at runtime.starter.MPJRun.main(MPJRun.java:1238)
```

How can I solve? I've already defined `MPJ_HOME` in Eclipse.

Comment: If you trying to solve such issue in NetBeans use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33484550/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-netbeans-8-0-2). Method 1 from third section. It worked for me.
UPD: this message is for users, who will find this post one of first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I find out where the problem was!

I already have inserted in `RunConfiguration>Tab "Arguments">Button "Variables...">Edit Variable>New Variable` the correct values:

```
Name: MPJ_HOME
Value: /path/to/mpj
Description: [What you want]
```

and in `RunConfiguration>Tab "Arguments">TextField "VM Arguments"` this value: `-jar ${MPJ_HOME}/lib/starter.jar -np 4`

After that I missed to do so:
RunConfiguration>Tab "Environment">New... and insert the following values:

```
Name: MPJ_HOME
Value: ${MPJ_HOME}
```

With this configuration everything is working.

I know that this is a real stupid problem but I hope that this answer could help someone.